# not able to extract the "img" link from xml in python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

tried to navigate inside  to extract IMG it does not work. will be a great help if someone can assist.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import reimport lxml

my_feeds = ['http://theverge.com/rss/index.xml']

for my_feed in my_feeds:
    url=urllib.request.urlopen(my_feed)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(url,"lxml")
    entries=soup.find_all(['item','entry'])

    for entry in entries:
       print(entry.title.get_text())
       img=entry.find("img")
       print(img)
```

Comment: Where is the code that tries to extract the image? What stack trace do you get? The code you provided executes just fine, so I'm unsure what to help you with.

Comment: updated the last 2 lines. i removed the last part of the code since it was taking me no. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find a tag in a text string. I would advise you to find your image via `regex`.

You could use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import lxml
import re

my_feeds = ['http://theverge.com/rss/index.xml']

for my_feed in my_feeds:
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(my_feed)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
    entries = soup.find_all(['item','entry'])

    for entry in entries:
       img = entry.find("content")
       image = re.search(r'(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")', img.get_text())
       print (image.group(0))
```

The print in the code will return this:

`https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/0Wln5lVNkZOj2RFrl9MXRz9rkOE=/0x0:2996x1997/1310x873/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53417309/643062258.0.jpg
https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/700q2QbDYoy9DW00Ud65RmEFfwM=/3x0:2283x1520/1310x873/cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53415747/seiko_steve_jobs_4.0.jpg ...`

Comment: Thanks @Zrog. This helps with this speific feed but if i change the feed ("https://www.wired.com/category/gear/feed/") and replace "content" with "description", getting error "    print (image.group(0))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'". Any suggestion?

Comment: On that feed you have a CDATA item. You can fetch it directly in that case. Example `img = entry.find("description")  print (img.find_all("img"))`

Comment: Thanks @Zorg. I used try and except to get the img url data. is there a better way to code this?

Comment: my_feeds = ['http://www.theverge.com/microsoft/rss/index.xml','https://www.wired.com/category/gear/feed/']

for my_feed in my_feeds:
    url=urllib.request.urlopen(my_feed)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(url,"lxml")
    entries=soup.find_all(['item','entry'])
    print(soup.title.string)
    for entry in entries:
        print(entry.title.get_text())
        img = entry.find(['content','description'])    
        try:
            image = re.search(r'(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")', img.get_text())
            print (image.group(0))
        except:
            print(img.find_all("img"))